# Align Text box in dropdown towards left css

Tags: html, css

Need help to display the text box to the  left side of **Track**. This is what it should look like.

[image]

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #94CB32;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Track</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <input type="text" placeholder="OrderID" ID="Button1" Text="Track">
    <input type="button" value="Track" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean you need exactly? Do you need the text box and button side by side? Do you want the pop-up form fields to show up to the left of the link? (Can you sketch out what you want in MS Paint or something?)

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/2enb093.png[/IMG]                                                                             I want to make it look like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to `.dropdown-content`:

```
top: 0;
right: calc( 100% + 5px );
```

**Note** that when you hover one element to show another you have to be careful about the placement. If there is a gap between the parent element and the child element you'll no longer be hovering the parent element and the child will disappear. To fix this you need both elements to touch one another. You can do this by making sure they touch (butted up next to each other or overlap on another), add padding (which might not be ideal if using a background color) or use a pseudo element. I did the latter so I added this selector:

```
.dropdown-content:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  top: 0;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This solution does what you have show in your image but I'm not sure how you want (are going to) handle the space to the left of the `.dropdown`. I reduced the width of `body` so you can see it fly out.

```css
body {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Fills gap between Track and flyout so it will continue to show when moving mouse. */
.dropdown-content:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  top: 0;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc( 100% + 5px );
  background-color: #94CB32;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Track</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <input type="text" placeholder="OrderID" ID="Button1" Text="Track">
    <input type="button" value="Track" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thankyou. But can i make that drop-down disappear slowly

Comment: @Melwin I updated my answer, there was a slight bug in that once you moved your cursor off of **Track** the flyout disappeared. I've also included a short explanation.

Comment: TYSM. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

it's simple, use `display: flex` for the dropcontent

check the updated snippet

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #94CB32;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<html>


<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Track</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <input type="text" placeholder="OrderID" ID="Button1" Text="Track">
    <input type="button" value="Track" />

  </div>


</div>

</html>
```

Comment: But the textbox  and button  does not appear on the left of track

Comment: Can you please check the question again about what you've asked for? If needed please update your question